# Flutter app stuck on black screen while installing apk on debug mode

Tags: flutter, debugging, installation, screen, flutter-apk

While building Flutter app, it is stucking on black screen while installing apk on debug mode. As per I found this is an issue on Android 13 for Vivo phones. I was earlier found on Android 11 but later it was solved on Android 12. Again, this issue is found on Android 13. Does anyone have idea on this issue except downgrading to Android 12 ?

I tried everything except downgrading to Android 12 and Native app is running well but not Flutter app.

Comment: share your code and error.

Comment: @Sagar Kafle did you find any soltion?